# How to spy on a decorated method with Jest when the decorator might prevent method execution?

Tags: typescript, ts-jest

I've been using decorators in my TypeScript project to augment method behavior. I've encountered a particular case where the decorator might prevent the actual method from executing. I want to write unit tests using Jest to verify exactly this behavior: whether the decorated method got called or not.

For instance, I have the following class with a hypothetical CacheDecorator:

```js
class TestClass {
  @CacheDecorator
  async methodToTest(arg1: string, arg2: number) {
    return { arg1, arg2 };
  }
}
```

The `CacheDecorator` checks a cache, and if the cache has a valid entry, it returns the cached value and does not execute `methodToTest`. If there's no valid cache entry, it lets `methodToTest` run.

I want to test if `methodToTest` gets called depending on cached conditions. But when I attempt to spy on `methodToTest` directly using `jest.spyOn()`, I am unable to differentiate between the decorator behavior and the actual method call.

How can I effectively spy on `methodToTest` to determine if it was executed, given this decorator's behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is distinguishing the decorator's behavior from the method's own behavior.

## 1. Delegate the actual logic to a separate "inner" method

Instead of placing the core logic within the decorated method, you can delegate this to an internal method in the class:

```js
class TestClass {
  async internalExecution(arg1: string, arg2: number) {
    return { arg1, arg2 };
  }

  @CacheDecorator
  async methodToTest(arg1: string, arg2: number) {
    return await this.internalExecution(arg1, arg2);
  }
}
```

## 2. Spy on the "inner" method

With your Jest tests, you can then spy on `internalExecution` rather than the decorated `methodToTest`.

```js
const instance = new TestClass();
const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'internalExecution');
await instance.methodToTest('testArg1', 123);
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

By spying on `internalExecution`, you directly monitor the actual method logic, isolated from the decorator's influence. This gives a clear indicator of whether the decorator allowed `methodToTest` to run its logic or if it returned early due to cached data.